# Set default font size (not font name) in nsTextView

Tags: textview, nstextview, nsfont

Using Swift (with import Cocoa) in xCode, I am trying to set the default font size of a TextView window. I see that I can set the default font name and size this way:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBOutlet var textView: NSTextView!  
...
override func viewDidAppear() {
    let document = self.view.window?.windowController?.document as! Document
    textView.textStorage?.setAttributedString(document.text)
    textView.font = NSFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 18);
}
```

And I think I see that I need to use nsUserFontOfSize to specify only the point size, but I can't figure out the syntax after much searching. Exactly what should the syntax be in place of the string "NSFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 18);"?

Comment: Go to the [documentation of NSFont](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsfont) and find "userfont": [class func userFont(ofSize fontSize: CGFloat) -> NSFont?](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsfont/1524559-userfont).

Comment: Thank you - I see that this is the answer, but I'm too much of a beginner to get the actual line of code that I should use. (I've been trying since you posted the answer.) If you're feeling generous (again), I'll be very grateful for the line of code; if not, this points me in the right direction, and I'll keep trying to figure it out.

Comment: Some progress: This changes the font style and the size: textView.font = NSFont.userFont(ofSize: CGFloat(18)); So I'm getting closer, but not quite there yet. - EDIT: and maybe it's simply not possible to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Do you want to set the default font size of the text view or do you want to change the font size of the text in the text view?

Comment: Thank you for coming back to this. I think the answer is "set a default font size in the text view." What I'm trying to do is this: if the text view opens plain text, or RTF etc. with no font size specified, then display the default font size that I set in my code. If the RTF/DOC/DOCX, etc. specifies a font size, then use the specified size. I'm not at all sure this is even possible. I would be very happy just to set a default font size and preserve the font name if one is in the data. Again, many thanks for your generosity and patience.

Comment: If you create the `NSAttributedString` with `init(url:options:documentAttributes:)`, you can specify default attributes in the `options` parameter.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed to sort this out. Thank you again. (I know this would be obvious to an experienced programmer, so thank you for your patience.)